# disable $numberLong for 64 bit int values when converting BSON to JSON

Tags: c++, json, mongodb

I'm using the mongodb c++ BSON library. I recently upgraded to use mongodb 3.0 and now serializing BSON with 64 bit ints gives:

```
{"time": {"$numberLong": "123"}}
```

when I call this:

```
BSON("time" << time).jsonString()
```

My client code can't handle this and instead needs the json:

```
{"time": 123}
```

How do I get the old behaviour of mongodb 2.4?

Comment: Same question for java new driver.

Comment: For java, the issue is when using The `Document` class (e.g. `MongoCollection<Document>`). using `BasicDBObject` solves the problem.